# Varnishstat is showing 0 (zero) hitrate ratio

Tags: varnish

I am running varnish v. 3.04 on a debian server.  I have had varnish running on this server for a long while now and I am not having any problems with the installation except:

when I run varnishstat, my hit ratio is 0, and when I run varnishstat -1 it shows 0 client connections accepted.

There are values in other misc. items such as backend_busy, backend_reuse

The varnishtop utility shows activity as expected.

I am quite certain varnish is serving the data and even getting cache hits through the use of tools like http://www.isvarnishworking.com/

The site name is http://events.floydecovillage.com if you'd like to see for yourself.

I can add that I upgraded varnish from 3.0.2-3 to 3.0.4-1 in August of last year.

EDIT:  I can also add that the server uptime displayed in the upper left hand corner of varnish stat is stuck on: 0+00:00:32

Comment: well your site is reporting a `X-Varnish-Cache: HIT` so it's working alright, I don't know though why your site is reporting 0

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your hostname changed since Varnish was started?  To support running multiple instances on a single host, Varnish allows you to give each instance a name which determines where it keeps its temporary files and other state.  One of these files is the shared memory log (a file named `_.vsm`) which utilities such as `varnishstat` get information about the running Varnish instance.

If no `-n whatever` option is specified (either on the `varnishd` or `varnishstat` command line), it defaults to the current hostname of the machine.  Check the `/var/lib/varnish` directory to find what names might have been used (each name will correspond to a subdirectory.)  You can then run `varnishstat -n whatever` to view statistics of any specific instance.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Andy.  I did experiment with the -n parameter, but it did not resolve the problem.  I found another person that had the identical symptoms and he recommended uninstalling, wiping all configuration files/directories and reinstalling.  That's what I did, and all is well now.